How to count ID when exting twice ore more often
I need help in creating a query that gives me a correct output.
I have a table with the sample output:



ID
Hour




1
09:00


1
11:00


2
09:00


2
11:00


3
09:00


3
10:00


3
11:00


4
09:00


4
11:00


5
11:00



The output should look like:



CNT_ID
Hour




4
09:00


1
11:00



All other entries should be ignored.
How can I create this query I already tried it with MIN(HOUR) but this doesn't work, because if an ID with only 11:00 exists it won't be shown.

Please add the attempted query to the question.

You want to count each ID only in the first hour it occurs. That is easily done: Get the minimum hour per ID, then count per hour:
select hour, count(*)
from
(
  select id, min(hour) as hour
  from mytable
  group by id
) each_id_with_its_first_hour
group by hour
order by hour;


If I understand correctly you want this: Take the least hour, count its IDs. Take the next least hour, count its IDs, except for those we already counted. Take the next least hour, count its IDs, except for those we already counted.
So, look at one hour and use NOT IN or NOT EXISTS to remove IDs from the counting that occur in an earlier hour.
One way, getting the hours first and then counting in subqueries:
with hours as (select distinct hour from mytable)
select
  hour,
  (
    select count(*)
    from mytable t
    where t.hour = h.hour
    and t.id not in
    (
      select id
      from mytable before
      where before.hour < t.hour
    )
  ) as cnt
from hours h
order by hours;

Another, stripping the rows we don't want to count right away:
with data as
(
  select hour, id
  from mytable t
  where id not in
  (
    select id
    from mytable before
    where before.hour < t.hour    
  )
)
select hour, count(*) as cnt
from data
group by hour
order by hour;

This second option would be my preference, as we aggregate the table only once.

Sounds good and is working in normal DB, but is there a way to do it without using the table twice? This is not possible in my case

You can't use the same table twice in a query? Weird. But yes, there exist other approaches. One is using a recursive query, but Impala doesn't support it, it seems (https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/plain-html/topics/impala_with.html). However, thinking about the task a little more, I've come up with a very simple solution. I've posted it as a separate answer.

You can use the following,
select id, min(hour) from mytable
group by id

Ensure your 'hour' Column is in 'Time'/'Timestamp' type .

I need a count of the IDs, therefore the column name CNT_ID
